# error on MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize() c#?

Tags: c#, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using miniprofiler in MVC project on App_Start() method I invoke

```
  MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize()
```

and I get the error :

```
     the Entity Framework was already using a DbConfiguration 
instance before an attempt was made to add an 'Loaded' event handler.
 'Loaded' event handlers can only be added as part of application start
 up before the Entity Framework is used. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for more information.
```

Comment: you should add better tags for your question. I think that c# is not enough.

Comment: somewhere in your code, you are trying to access your DB but you need to add this line `MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize()` before accessing the DB

Answer (score 2):

try to add  MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize() in application_start function of your Global.asax and make sure **it is the first line there.**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
            {          
                  StackExchange.Profiling.EntityFramework6.MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();

    }
```

Comment: Did this, it still crashes

Comment: What kind of Crash do you get?

Comment: There was already a Initializer loaded, or something in that vein. I started debugging a bit more and it seems there is something built on top of Unity and IUnitOfWork that initialises before Application_Start is even executed

Answer (score 2):

If you have any `PreApplicationStartMethod`'s any where in the project, then make sure you move your `MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize()` from `Global.asax` to that class Start method

In my case I use static StructuremapMvc class to setup Ioc, and have

so have

```
    [assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(StructuremapMvc), "Start")]
    public static class StructuremapMvc {
       public static void Start() {
                MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
...
...
```

this fixed for me.