# Getting Error in Miniprofiler in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, miniprofiler

I am getting following error during integration of miniprofiler

*The Entity Framework was already using a DbConfiguration instance before an attempt was made to add an 'Loaded' event handler. 'Loaded' event handlers can only be added as part of application start up before the Entity Framework is used. See [this](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883) for more information.*

**Below is code of Global.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
            StackExchange.Profiling.EntityFramework6.MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
             //MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
....
....
}
```

I am using

- I am using ASP.NET MVC 4
- EF 6 (Code first )

**I searched this google but couldn't find any solution**

Comment: is this `StackExchange.Profiling.EntityFramework6.MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize()` the first line on the `Application_Start()` method ?

Comment: @Sampath - Yes this is first line

Comment: This is a duplicate question please see the answer error on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776510/error-on-miniprofileref6-initialize-c/42098605#42098605